# Card design in CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive-design, css-selectors

I've been asked to design this section of a webpage from figma
[image]

Using the figma tools I can see that it is a card of 453 x 512 px and has a padding of 30px on top left and bottom and image is 393 x280 px . There is a 30px margin between the card image and card body after which it is a standard h1 paragraph and link tag. The following is my code implementation.

```css
.blog {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.blog .icons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.card {
  width: 453px;
  height: 512px;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section class="blog">
  <h1>We have Most of Popular Departments</h1>
  <div class="icons">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./assets/ai.svg" alt="image1" class="top" />
      <h3>Artificial Intelligence</h3>
      <p>
        Assertively parallel task synergistic deliverables after high-quality.
      </p>
      <a href="#">Learn More</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-top">
        <img src="./assets/civil.svg" alt="image1" />
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h3>Civil Engineering</h3>
        <p>
          Assertively parallel task synergistic deliverables after high-quality.
        </p>
        <a href="#">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./assets/business.svg" alt="image1" class="top" />
      <h3>Business Strategy</h3>
      <p>
        Assertively parallel task synergistic deliverables after high-quality.
      </p>
      <a href="#">Learn More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary">View All Departments</button>
</section>
```

This what my card looks like:

[image: Output from HTML CSS]

Comment: Is that all of the relevant css you use?

Comment: For this section that is all I use because the CSS of the other elements imo would not affect it but would it help if I shared that too ?

Comment: How are you ensuring the images you use have the correct aspect ratio?

Comment: Yea the thing is I copied it as a svg from figma so that I can get the exact resolution onto the card image but for some reason it is not taking up its entire height which I specified in the question( 280px)

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution and it works pretty well. Here is the code.

```
  <div class="cards">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="/Untitled.png" alt="" />
          <div class="container">
            <h1>Artificial Intelligence</h1>
            <p>
              Assertively parallel task synergistic deliverables after
              high-quality.
            </p>
            <a href="#"
              >Learn More <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right-long"></i
            ></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <img src="/Untitled.png" alt="" />
          <div class="container">
            <h1>Artificial Intelligence</h1>
            <p>
              Assertively parallel task synergistic deliverables after
              high-quality.
            </p>
            <a href="#"
              >Learn More <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right-long"></i
            ></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <img src="/Untitled.png" alt="" />
          <div class="container">
            <h1>Artificial Intelligence</h1>
            <p>
              Assertively parallel task synergistic deliverables after
              high-quality.
            </p>
            <a href="#"
              >Learn More <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right-long"></i
            ></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

In styles.css

```
.cards {
  display: flex;
}

.cards .card {
  margin-right: 31px;
}
.cards .card:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.card {
  height: 512px;
  width: 453px;
  padding: 30px;

  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: 0.3s all ease-in;
}
.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px #2b2a2a;
}

.card img {
  width: 393px;
  height: 280px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
}

.card h1 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 34px;
}
.card p {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  overflow: auto;
  color: #6f6f76;
  max-width: 393px;
}
.card a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffa502;
}
```

Output looks like this :
[image]

Now I have encountered a new problem. When I am building out the entire container whose specification is as follows :
[image]

The h1 and cards are enclosed in a container of 1421 x 698 px and there is a h1 which is centered in the container with a dimension of 443 x116 px. Now if I want to apply a height and width to a inline element I should set it as `display:inline-block` and apply `height` and `width` properties. But when I do so this happens :
[image]

Why is the width and height of a h1 element affecting the elements of card ?

HTML Code:

```
 <section class="cards-container">
     <h1>We have most popular departments</h1>
<div class="cards">...</div>


    </section>
```

Styles.css :

```
/* Cards Container */
.cards-container {
  width: 1421px;
  height: 698px;
  /* display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; */
}

.cards-container h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  display: block;
  width: 443px;
  height: 116px;
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```